# IronPDF - Use different nuget source for downloading platform specific dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core, ironpdf

Our dev environment is behind Firewall and default NuGet url is blocked and we use a custom NuGet repo url for downloading package.

IronPdf tries to download `IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows version 2022.2.4868` in runtime from  `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows/2022.2.4868` which is blocked and returns error message saying `Failed downloading NuGet package at runtime`

I have tried manually adding that package to the project but it is still not included in the build output and IronPdf again tries to retrieve from NuGet

How to

1. Include the Native package in deployed output

OR

2. Configure NuGet source in IronPdf

Comment: Have you added the IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows package to your project? IronPdf only attempts to download the native package if deployment failed (usually it's a permissions issue, when there is no write access to the project bin folder and temp folder)

Answer (score 0):

As the comment under your post suggests, this is most likely a permission issue with your `temp` or `bin` directory where IronPdf is attempting to deploy the dependencies it extracts from that package.

In our case, IronPdf was attempting to deploy the Chrome dependencies to, `\runtimes\win-64x\native`, in our deployment directory. We use service accounts for our IIS App Pool Identities, so we gave full permissions over the entire deployment (web) directory where the IIS Web Site is pointing to  and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Is there a way to get the package to be included? It is often not allowed for production systems to retrieve NuGet packages directly. So, merely granting permissions for the folder isn't going to work.

Comment: I would reach out to their support team for that. Although, I will say, in our situation it seems the package (once downloaded) is placed directly into the root of our deployment directory and then unpacked to a temp folder that it creates. You could download the package and deploy it straight to the root deployment directory and see if it will unpack it. Since it doesn't contain an actual .dll in it's `<lib>` folder, you can't reference it. You'll still need to add permissions so it can create the temp and runtimes folder.